# How to install/enable mediaelement.js plugins in WordPress

Tags: plugins, media

`MediaElement.js` has a lot of useful plugins, such as [jump forward](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins/blob/master/docs/jump-forward.md), [skip back](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins/blob/master/docs/skip-back.md), [speed](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins/blob/master/docs/speed.md), etc.

From my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong) WordPress core contains *only* `MediaElement.js` -- without these plugins enabled.

So,

1) How do I install (or enable) the `MediaElement.js` plugins (listed here [https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins)](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins) in Wordpress 5+?

2) Is there more than one method?

3) If there is more than one method, what is the best practice?

Comment: I'm in the same boat as yourself, it's included in WordPress, but what is it actually doing and how do we leverage it in our sites? There just doesn't seem to be any documentation as to how to actually use it in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

## Known Issues / Required Modifications

There is a slight issue with the Mediaelement plugins and string translations. I'm not entirely sure if this is an issue with core Mediaelement or if it has something to do with WordPresses implementation.

If we were to take [Jump-Forward](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins/tree/release_2.6.3/dist/jump-forward) for example and take a look at its [unminified JS](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins/blob/release_2.6.3/dist/jump-forward/jump-forward.js#L14) it has:

```
mejs.i18n.en['mejs.time-jump-forward'] = ['Jump forward 1 second', 'Jump forward %1 seconds'];
```

During the build process, Mediaelement is trying to run [`str = str.replace('%1', pluralParam);`](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/5.1.0/build/mediaelement-and-player.js#L643) where `str` is the array seen above and will error out (`pluralParam` being the default `jumpForwardInterval` 30).

```
error building jumpforward TypeError: n.replace is not a function
```

Or, with [`SCRIPT_DEBUG`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#script_debug) enabled

```
error building jumpforward TypeError: str.replace is not a function
```

To fix this, we need to remove the array declaration and use a string:

```
mejs.i18n.en['mejs.time-jump-forward'] = 'Jump forward %1 seconds';
```

There may be more issues similar to this, but the above would apply to both [jumpForward](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins/blob/release_2.6.3/docs/jump-forward.md) and [skipback](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins/blob/release_2.6.3/docs/skip-back.md) features.

---

## Implementation

The two main things are:

1. Register the Mediaelement plugin assets (JS and CSS).
2. Enqueue the assets when needed.
3. Add the plugin feature slug into the mejs settings.

The below code assumes a simple plugin where the Mediaelement library files are in an assets/js folder.

```
/**
 * Register the MEJS Plugins files.
 * Jump Forward (jumpforward)
 * Skip Back (skipback)
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse327599_mejs_plugin_assets() {

    // Jump Foward
    wp_register_script( 'jump-forward', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/jump-forward/jump-forward.min.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-mediaelement' ), '2.6.3', true );
    wp_register_style( 'jump-forward', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/jump-forward/jump-forward.min.css', array( 'wp-mediaelement' ), '2.6.3', 'screen' );

    // Skip Back
    wp_register_script( 'skip-back', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/skip-back/skip-back.min.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-mediaelement' ), '2.6.3', true );
    wp_register_style( 'skip-back', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/skip-back/skip-back.min.css', array( 'wp-mediaelement' ), '2.6.3', 'screen' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse327599_mejs_plugin_assets' );
```

We really only want to call the Mediaelement plugin files when needed so we'll use the [`wp_audio_shortcode` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_audio_shortcode/) to do so.

```
/**
 * Enqueue the MEJS plugin assets as needed.
 *
 * @param String $html
 * @param Array $atts
 * @param String $audio_file
 * @param Integer $post_id
 * @param String $library
 *
 * @return String $html
 */
function wpse327599_mejs_plugin_enqueue( $html, $atts, $audio_file, $post_id, $library ) {

    if( 'mediaelement' === $library && did_action( 'init' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jump-forward' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jump-forward' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'skip-back' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'skip-back' );
    }

    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'wp_audio_shortcode', 'wpse327599_mejs_plugin_enqueue', 10, 5 );
```

Unfortunately, using the [`mejs_settings`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/mejs_settings/) filter hook to add in features will remove all existing player buttons/features. You need to explicitly re-add these features. See the [MeidaelementPlayer docs](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/5.1.0/docs/api.md#player) for the full list of features. Additionally, see the [specific plugins docs](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-plugins#available-plugins) to find the feature slug as it may not be the script name.

```
/**
 * Overwrite the default MEJS settings
 *
 * @param Array $settings
 *
 * @return Array $settings
 */
function wpse327599_mejs_settings( $settings ) {

    return array_merge( array(
        'features' => array(
            'playpause',        // Play / Pause Button.
            'current',          // Time elapsed while playing.
            'jumpforward',      // Jump forward 30s button.
            'progress',         // Progress bar.
            'skipback',         // Skip backward 30s button.
            'duration',         // Total time of media file.
            'volume',           // Volume control.
        ),
    ), $settings );

}
add_filter( 'mejs_settings', 'wpse327599_mejs_settings' );
```

The feature order will also be how they appear on the player. For example, if you move `playpause` to the end of the above features array, the play/pause button will appear at the end of the media player.